# How to split the logic in a ruby game

Tags: ruby

Following "Learning Ruby the Hard Way" chapter 36, I am writing my own game. The player enters a kitchen. Whether he gets breakfast, lunch, or dinner depends on the time.

I wrote a function `clock` that gives:

```
time_of_day = t.strftime "%H:%M"
```

then checks to see if it's a Sunday. I wrote a `kitchen` function with an array of choices:

```
food_choice = ["breakfast", "lunch", "dinner"]
```

Where is it best to put the logic that determines which meal the character gets? I'm guessing in the `kitchen` function, so the clock stays clean. But I could put something in the `clock` function that returns

```
meal_choice = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

as it were.

Comment: I agree that `meal_choice` doesn't really belong in `Clock` but I can see `Clock` returning the `hour` and the `Kitchen` determining the `meal_choice` from the `hour`.  That gives you a lot of flexibility... in future if you decide to provide "brunch" only the `Kitchen` has to change.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can talk with your classes/functions to see if they have a single responsibility ( one of the OOP stuff ). This means that entity ( class or function ) has a purpose and everything it does is strictly bound to this purpose. E.G.

`Hey, mr. time, what time of the day is it?`

Sonds ok, right? Now you may ask the question:

`Hey, mr. kitchen - what are the meals for now?`

**P.S.** If your question sounds strange like `Mr. Man, what is you bicycle tire?` don't be afraid to create new entity: `mr. bicycle, what is you tire?` sound more good.

Comment: Thanks zmii, the asking questions metaphor works for me .. cheers.

Comment: These thought are from Sendi Metz - you can watch her conference talks - they are brilliant!